# Disable object identity check in symfony ACL

Tags: symfony, acl

I use voters that I set up based on [this guide](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html) (I know it's a Sonata guide but it uses no Sonata code).

Now the voters are working fine, they grant deny as needed. One voter service definition looks like this:

```
services:
    acme_account.security.authorization.organisation_voter:
        class: %acme_account.security.authorization.organisation_voter.class%
        arguments:  [@service_container]
        public: false
        tags:
          - { name: security.voter }
```

Now my problem is that even though the voter returns correct grants, in some cases some default ACL handler denies permission. This is in the logs:

> security.DEBUG: No ACL found for the object identity. Voting to deny access. [] []

Since I want to enforce the denies coming from the voters I have set the `security.access_decision_manager.strategy` to `unanimous`. But because of the default handler this way the permissions are denied.

Now of course I could configure and start using the ACLs but it would be an overkill in this application that's why I choose the voters.

Is there any way to disable this default behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a workaround for it, not sure if this is the best way but it works.

The object and security identity retrieval strategy services needed to be overwritten with noop implementations.

**services.yml**

```
security.acl.object_identity_retrieval_strategy:
    class: Acme\UserBundle\Acl\ObjectIdentityRetrievalStrategy

security.acl.security_identity_retrieval_strategy:
    class: Acme\UserBundle\Acl\SecurityIdentityRetrievalStrategy
```

**Acme\UserBundle\Acl\ObjectIdentityRetrievalStrategy.php**

```
<?php
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Acl;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Model\ObjectIdentityRetrievalStrategyInterface;

class ObjectIdentityRetrievalStrategy implements ObjectIdentityRetrievalStrategyInterface
{
    public function getObjectIdentity($domainObject)
    {
    }
}
```

**Acme\UserBundle\Acl\SecurityIdentityRetrievalStrategy.php**

```
<?php
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Acl;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Model\SecurityIdentityRetrievalStrategyInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;

class SecurityIdentityRetrievalStrategy implements SecurityIdentityRetrievalStrategyInterface
{
    public function getSecurityIdentities(TokenInterface $token)
    {
    }
}
```